# How do you find the title of a page in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

How do I find the title of a webpage in VB, and make the form title the title of the page?

Code:         Me.Text = WebBrowser1.DocumentTitle

Comment: @TimSchmelter: That (a) has nothing to do with HTML and (b) won't work.

Comment: @SLaks: i've posted the wrong `Page.Title`, voilà:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.title(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @TimSchmelter: That won't work either; it's for generating HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Use [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to find the content of the `<title>` tag.